# Program to make image buttons?

Tags: software-rec

Which program is used to make the kind of button you see on the screeenshot of a website below
 (the one with the little icon on the left and profile/email on the right):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

These are images, normally created using a photo editor such as Photoshop, Paint.Net or Gimp.